# mysqldbcopy - Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, bash, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

i am using mysql workbench which has the command `mysqldbcopy` under linux. when i am trying to use it, i have to supply a connection string (see the examples [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldbcopy.html)).

my password contains ampersand (&), thus i am invoking `mysqldbcopy` as follows (for character escaping propose)

```
mysqldbcopy \
    --source "root:&1qqq34rtyy@localhost:3310:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" \
    --destination "root:&1qqq34rtyy@localhost:3310:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" \
    old:new
```

but i receive the following error, which by googling, i found that it means that i do not supply the right password (correct me if i am wrong)

```
# Source on localhost: ... ERROR: Cannot connect to the Source server.
Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

could one please shed the light of where is the problem?

**and yes, i am sure that the password is correct, it has been copied from `.my.cnf`, and i am able to use it under `mysql` command**

Comment: You see the part that says **using password: NO** ? it means that you're trying to connect without using a password - so you must be looking in the wrong place...

Comment: @alfasin, if the command above is incorrect, could you please show the right way to invoke `mysqldbcopy`?

Comment: Maybe the `&` in the password is the problem - try changing the password to something that doesn't contain special characters

Answer (score 4):

**mysqldbcopy**

```
--source=root':&1qqq34rtyy'@localhost:3310:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  
--destination=root':&1qqq34rtyy'@localhost:3310:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
 old:new  --force
```

I have also faced same issue,

The above mentioned syntax executes smoothly without any error.
Use `--force`, if the destination database name already **exists** & needs to **overwrite** forcefully.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the link you provided, I can conclude this -

You are using -

```
mysqldbcopy \
    --source "root:&1qqq34rtyy@localhost:3310:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" \
    --destination "root:&1qqq34rtyy@localhost:3310:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" \
    old:new
```

But the link shows,

```
mysqldbcopy \   
    --source=root:pass@localhost:3310:/test123/mysql.sock \ 
    --destination=root:pass@localhost:3310:/test123/mysql.sock \   
   util_test:util_test_copy
```

Conclusions,

1. After `--source` and `--destination`, the example in the link you provided have **'='**.
2. Try with single quotes if double quotes doesn't help.
3. Verify if the port 3310 is correct. Default I guess when you install is 3306. Can you confirm?

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have tried both. by testing i can acknowledge that using `=` is not mandatory for correct parsing.

Comment: @MrRoth: Please check, I have edited my answer with new point 3 at last. Hope it helps!